# send multiple parameter to Azure-Devops pipeline job via Powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am able to kick off an Azure Devops Build job and send a text parameter but I only seem to be able to send a single parameter and not more.
I need to send a token parameter Ok that works but I also want to send a text param that contains a json payload to be processed by a Powershell script in the Build job.
So I have a Hellow World definition setup with two variables in Pipeline variables.
First one is tokentext the second one is jsonInput.
Both have the checkbox "Settable at queue time" checked.
I have a PowerShell Inline script in the job definition with this:

```
Write-Host "Hello World"
Write-Host "tokentext: $(tokentext) `n"

Write-Host "Json Input"
Write-Host "---------------------------------------------------"
$(jsonInput)
```

My Body that I am sending to the Invoke-RestMethod is:

```
$body = @{ 
definition = @{
    id = $buildDefID
}    
parameters = "{`"tokentext`" :$mytoken}
              {`"jsonInput`" :$j}  
"
}
$b = $body  | ConvertTo-Json
```

This works  but the above does not:

```
$body = @{ 
definition = @{
    id = $buildDefID
}    
parameters = "{`"tokentext`" :$mytoken}
"
}

$b = $body  | ConvertTo-Json
```

I have tried it with a comma separating the parameters etc.. All kids of things I have tried. I could sure use some assistance if anyone is sening multiple parameters to variables in a build Definition from a script.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below request body works for me. Please check it out.

```
$body = @{
  definition= @{id = $buildDefID};

  parameters ="{`"jsonInput`":`"$jsonInput`", `"tokentext`":`"$tokentext`"}"
 }
$b = $body  | ConvertTo-Json
```

You can also run your pipeline via [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api which is less complicated.

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.1`

`pipelineId` is the `$buildDefID`

You can put the parameters in your request body as below:

```
 $body=@{
     
     variables = @{
 
         jsonInput= @{value = $jsonInput};
     
         tokentext= @{value = $tokentext}
      }
  }

$b = $body  | ConvertTo-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```bsh
$body = @{ 
  definition = @{
    id = $buildDefID
  }    
  parameters = "{`"tokentext`" :$mytoken, `"jsonInput`" :$j}"
}
$b = $body  | ConvertTo-Json
```