# Trigger another build exist in project in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a repo name called `A` with its build pipeline as `azure-pipelines.yml`
Then I have another repo called `B` with its build pipeline as `azure-pipelines.yml`

Both `A` and `B` are under same project `ProjectA`

This is the flow for

1. repo A, `build => release (stages ops and dev)`
2. repo B, `Build create the Artifact and store the Artifact`

So, what I want to achieve is as soon as the release finished from repo A it should trigger build repo B.
My pipeline `A` looks like this :

```
name: SomethingFancy

trigger:
  - none

resources:
 containers:
    - container: docker
      image: docker:1.6
    - container: python3
      image: python:3

variables:
  major: 2
  minor: 0
```

So I made pipeline `B` looks like this:

```
name: 

trigger:
  - none

resources:
 pipelines:
   - pipeline: SomethingFancy
     source: azure-pipelines
     branch: DATA-1234
     project: ProjectA
     trigger:
      branches:
      - DATA-1234
     stages:
    - dev
    - ops
 containers:
    - container: docker
      image: docker:1.6
```

So far I'm not able to run the pipeline as it complains "Pipeline Resource SomethingFancy Input Must be Valid." as per the documentation it is something `# identifier for the resource (used in pipeline resource variables)`.

I'm referring to [this][1] for the collection of resources.

I'm also intended to use [api][2] call to queue the build of the `B`, but not able to find what should be the body of the post message e.g. how to add the branch of pipeline `B`, or how to pass the parameters to the pipeline of `B`

### EDIT

see attached my pipeline name
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
and build source pipeline also called `azurepipelines.yml` and release pipeline has one stage called `Dev`

Now my pipeline B looks like this:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: azurepipelines
    source: azurepipelines
    branch: DATA-1234
    project: ProjectA
    trigger:
      branches:
      - DATA-1234
      stages:
        - Dev
```

still I don't see any auto kick off of build pipeline of `B`.
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#resources-pipelines
[2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Uk7A.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of struggle and the help of wise people here I finally manage to tame the issue. I'm posting here so that anyone can take a referebce. This is working now refer:
[ListBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [QueueTheBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

```
name="ProjectA"
    curl --silent -X GET -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0 --output /tmp/response.json
    #Now get the build-id of your project you are interested in
    #please be aware that api-version > 6 has different json output and below command 
    #may not help you to give the right id
    id=$(cat /tmp/response.json | jq -r --arg key ${name} '.value[] | select(.name==$key)| .id'  --raw-output)
    #create your body to post
    generate_post_data()
    {
      cat <<EOF
    {
      "sourceBranch":"refs/heads/DATA-1234", 
      "definition":{"id": $id}
    }
    EOF
    }

#Now queue your build to run
#have to still verify if this command works for API_VERSION 6

curl -X POST \
                --silent \
                -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  \
                -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6  \
--output /tmp/response1.json \
-d "$(generate_post_data)"
#check the outcome
cat /tmp/response1.json
```

Answer (score 0):

As I read from the same documentation I think you should set the `source` property to the name of your pipeline from repo A. `source: SomethingFancy`

Comment: still not working,  how exactly A and B will communicate, which one is the repo name. in both repo the pipeline has the same name.

Comment: Aure the names of the pipelines also the same in the ADO web UI? Try specifying the name of the pipeline you see in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks like it's telling you it cannot find a pipeline with the name you specified, probably because, `name` means refers to the build numbering format in pipeline YAML e.g.

```
name: $(BuildID)
```

As @Roderick noted, the name of the pipeline should be what you see in the UI. From the main "Azure Pipelines" screen in your project. First click the "three dots" to get a submenu and then click "Rename/move". Example screenshot:

[image: Azure DevOps - Rename Pipelines]

So now you should have the project name and pipeline names you need to update your YAML in pipeline B and it should work.

Comment: it's still not kicking in....please see the updated question to see what I did after your great suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the the flow for repo A is `build => release (stages ops and dev)`. I wonder if the `build` is the build pipeline as `azure-pipelines.yml`, and `release (stages ops and dev)` is the classic release pipeline in azure devops Releases hub? You should know that pipeline resources triggers doesnot work for classic release pipeline.

`build => release (stages ops and dev)` for repo A should be in the same pipeline (ie. azure-pipelines.yml). So the pipeline resources trigger you defined in pipeline B only works when the pipeline A looks like below:

```
name: ..
trigger:
  - none
resources:
 containers:
    ..
variables:
  ..

stages:
- stage: build  # build the project in build stage
  jobs:
  - job 
    ..

- stage: ops    #stage ops
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...

- stage: dev    #stage dev
  jobs:
  - job:
    ...
```

The `source` in Pipeline B is the name of the pipeline A as julie-ng mentioned. See below example:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: {Can be Any String} #identifier for the resource (used in pipeline resource variables)
    source: {Name of the pipeline A what you see in the UI}  #name of the pipeline that produces an artifact
```

**Name of the pipeline A**:

[image]

**Resource trigger in Pipeline B:**

```
resources:
 pipelines:
   - pipeline: AnyString
     source: pipelineA
     branch: DATA-1234
```

If the release pipeline for repo A is the classic release pipeline. You can add this external task [Trigger Build](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) in stage dev to trigger pipeline B in stage dev:

```
- task: benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks.trigger-build-task.TriggerBuild@3
  displayName: 'Trigger a new build of 48'
  inputs:
    buildDefinition: {ID of pipeline B}
    buildParameters: 'variableName: variableValue'  
    password: '$(System.AccessToken)'
```

If you want to pass some variables from Pipeline A to pipeline B. you can use the `buildParameters` field.

> In pipelien B, Click the Variables button to define a Variable to the hold the variable value. (Note: Check this option Let users override this value when running this pipeline, so that it can be overrode from A pipeline )

You can always use the Rest api to trigger the pipeline. Please see below threads for more inforamtion

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483072/how-to-queue-a-new-build-using-vsts-rest-api) thread

[send multiple parameter to Azure-Devops pipeline job via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213867/send-multiple-parameter-to-azure-devops-pipeline-job-via-powershell/64219493#64219493)

[Can you pass a file to an azure pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63922636/can-you-pass-a-file-to-an-azure-pipeline)

Update:

You can use [Builds - Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) rest api To trigger a pipeline.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6
```

See below example:

```
curl -X POST --silent \
-H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  \  
-H "Content-Type:application/json" \ 
        $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6 \

-d '{  
     "definition":{ "id": id-of-pipelineB}, 
     "sourceBranch":"refs/heads/DATA-1234"
    }'
```

Comment: thanks, my pipeline is a classic pipeline, and after reading your input. I gave up using the resource trigger. However, I have started using the API build queue to call the build pipeline for repo `B` @ DATA-1234 after stage Dev of  `A`, I got the build-id and project id using api call and then calling `POST` to initiate the build pipeline. Now it throws me this error `"message":"The request specifies project ID 0b330b4e-1ecb-47e7-854f-e6e799833627 but the supplied pipeline specifies project ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000."` see below post to check the API call.

Comment: `curl -X POST \
                --silent \
                -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  \
                -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0  \
--output /tmp/response1.json \
-d'{
                  "id":"$id",
                  "sourceBranch":"refs/heads/DATA-1234",
                  "project":{"name":"ProjectA", "id":"$project_id"}
                  }'`  so I don't get it where project ID 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 coming from. Any thought?

Comment: @change198 It looks like you were using the wrong rest api. Above api you used is for creating a pipeline definition not queuing a build. You should use builds queue rest api to trigger a pipeline. See above update.

Comment: @change198 Did you check out above update, how did it go?

Comment: Now it's giving me `"message":"TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: acbae1be-ceb0-4cc1-a1df 453211e2d8c6.", "typeName": "Newtonsoft.Json. JsonReaderException, Newtonsoft.Json","typeKey":"JsonReaderException"` I don't know what I'm doing wrong? `curl -X POST  --silent -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"  -H "Content-Type:application/json" $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?api-version=6.1-preview.6  --output /tmp/response1.json -d '{
   "sourceBranch":"refs/heads/DATA-1234",
   "definition":{
      "id": $id
   }
}'`

Comment: If I replace $id with the actual value it works but as soon as I make it parameterized it throws the error.

Comment: @change198 try wrapping `$id` in` $()` in request body. like this `$($id)`

Comment: still not working this is what I'm doing`curl --silent -X GET -H "Authorization:Bearer $(System.AccessToken)" -H "Content-Type:application/json"  $(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0 --output /tmp/response.json` and then `id=$(cat /tmp/response.json | jq -r --arg key ${name} '.value[] | select(.name==$key)| .id'  --raw-output)` and then the `POST API call with the id`. I'm using 6.0 api-version because it seems the json outout of 6.1 has changed. and key is the project name.

Comment: It's working now, but still don't know what was wrong in JSON. So I call the `POST` in with JSON in a different way. See the Answer I have added it. Thanks.

Comment: @change198 That is great you worked it out. I was checking the json data too. Could you accept above answer, since the issue was fixed? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I just did. thanks. Is it ok, if we move this conversation to chat.

Comment: ＠change198 sure, you can. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224777/discussion-between-change198-and-levi-lu-msft).